# how to add asynch method call in protractor jasmine suite

Tags: protractor

I have a use case where I need to call a asynchronous method in protractor jasmine at one point of line, but it is executing firstly before the preceding statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for promises to resolve.Use callbacks